# Different choices for inputting text into database

Tags: database, text, cjk

I am making a database of images. Each image has a certain amount of Chinese text in it. When I have made the database, I want to be able to search the text and find the image it is attached to, and vice-versa.

In each image, the largest and highest-up-the-page text is the "main text", and the rest are "secondary text". In a few images, the amount of discrete secondary texts is high (>10 pieces). The images' text varies quite a lot, so the chances that one image will have the same text as another are small. See an example image (below) where there is one main text (某词), and three secondary texts (战略, 微笑, 容易).

My question is: Should I have two columns in my "images" table, where the first column is "main text" and the other column is "secondary text", containing all other text in the image? Or should I have multiple columns allowing for X number of discrete secondary texts? I have so far assumed that it would be relatively meaningless to create a "text" table and connect it with the images table via an associative table, since the majority of the texts are unique.

**A problem**: Because the images I am looking at largely do not use punctuation, and Chinese characters are not written with spaces between them, having one column for all "secondary text" could very easily lead to query confusions. For example, if I take all three pieces secondary text in the example image (战略, 微笑 and 容易) and concatenate them, it becomes 战略微笑容易. But now, this has become a text containing potentially five words: 战略, 略微, 微笑, 笑容, 容易. This would create chaos in my queries.

[image: example image1]

Comment: include images as part of the post. Try to be concise.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way would probably be to create a separate table for (at least secondary) texts. If they are largely unique you can do this without an association table.

Table `images`:

```
ID | image | main text
---+-------+----------
 1 | <img> | 某词
```

Table `secondary`:

```
ID | image_id | secondary text
---+----------+---------------
 1 |        1 | 战略
 2 |        1 | 微笑 
 3 |        1 | 容易
```

If it fits your use case better, you could also put all your texts along with their type into the second table:

Table `images`:

```
ID | image 
---+-------
 1 | <img>
```

Table `text`:

```
ID | image_id | text | type
---+----------+------+----------
 1 |        1 |  战略 | 2
 2 |        1 |  微笑 | 2
 3 |        1 |  容易 | 2
 4 |        1 |  某词 | 1
```